# CRUD из мануала Yii2

Tags: php, yii2

Почему, при создании cruda, с помощью генератора, не работает редактирование и добавление, а удаление работает?

При добавлении пишет ошибку **Отсутствуют обязательные параметры: id**

```
 public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model = new Country();

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->code]);
        }

        return $this->render('create', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }

<?php

namespace app\models;

use yii\db\ActiveRecord;

class Country extends ActiveRecord
{
      public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'country';
    }
}
```

---

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.3.11
-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
--
-- Хост: 127.0.0.1
-- Время создания: Фев 17 2018 г., 12:20
-- Версия сервера: 5.6.24
-- Версия PHP: 5.6.8

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;

--
-- База данных: `yii2`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Структура таблицы `country`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `country` (
  `code` char(2) NOT NULL,
  `name` char(52) NOT NULL,
  `population` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Дамп данных таблицы `country`
--

INSERT INTO `country` (`code`, `name`, `population`) VALUES
('AU', 'Australia', 24016400),
('BR', 'Brazil', 205722000),
('CA', 'Canada', 35985751),
('CN', 'China', 1375210000),
('DE', 'Germany', 81459000),
('FR', 'France', 64513242),
('GB', 'United Kingdom', 65097000),
('IN', 'India', 1285400000),
('RU', 'Russia', 146519759);

--
-- Индексы сохранённых таблиц
--

--
-- Индексы таблицы `country`
--
ALTER TABLE `country`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`code`);

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

Я разобрался, это потому что не было правил

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['code', 'name'], 'required'],
            [['population'], 'integer'],
            [['code'], 'string', 'max' => 2],
            [['name'], 'string', 'max' => 52],
            [['code'], 'unique'],
        ];
    }
```

Не понимаю, а почему без правил не работает?

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я помню CRUD нужен первичный ключ в таблице, что бы он работал из коробки. Вполне логично,если поведение не соответствует стандартной дать возможность просматривать и не давать ничего больше пока не напишешь правила